# SQL Query find month/year and then calculate difference from start date

Tags: datediff

Assume I have a table with a column Start_Date. I like to know how we can build a query so we can find the end of the month date based on the start_ date and then calculate the difference

For example lets say we have a date 12/06/2014 and now based on this we should get the end of the month date which is 30/06/2014. Now we can get the difference which is 18 days.

Thanks

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: if it is SQL Server 2012, you can use EOMONTH to get the last date of the month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using MySQL then you can use this :

```
 select ( day(last_day(start_date)) - day(start_date) ) as difference_date
  from table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work with an Oracle database you can do the folowing:

```
select last_day(sysdate) - sysdate from dual
```